# What is itfoxtec-identity-saml2 Issuer in adfs setup?

Tags: adfs, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm setting up [ITfoxtec Identity SAML2](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) for ADFS. What should be used as Issuer for ADFS setup?
And where to get SingleSignOnDestination?

Many thanks

Comment: I'd suggest this question moves under https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ . The SO site is more focused on software development.

Answer (score 1):

The application can read the AD FS issuer and SingleSignOnDestination in the AD FS metadata:
https://`--adfs domain--`/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml

The AD FS metadata URL is configured in the relying party IdPMetadata, please see the ASP.NET Core sample config line 11:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L11

The sample application loads the AD FS metadata in Startup.cs: https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L40